# Generators of the quotient group given the generators of the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to practise these exercises in the Dummit and Foote textbook and there's this one question I can't figure out. It says:

If $N \unlhd G$ and $\bar{G} = G/N$. Prove that if $G=\langle x,y\rangle  \implies \bar{G}= \langle\bar{x},\bar{y}\rangle$. Here $\bar{x}$  denotes the coset corresponding to $x$ of $N$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the definition of the operation on the quotient group. Let $gN\in G/N$. Since $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ we know that there are some $t_1,...,t_n\in\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\}$ such that $g=t_1t_2...t_n$. But then:

$gN=(t_1...t_n)N=(t_1N)(t_2N)...(t_nN)$

So every coset is a finite product of elements from $\{xN,yN,(xN)^{-1},(yN)^{-1}\}$. Hence $G/N=\langle xN,yN\rangle$.

Comment: May I ask why you didn't include $x^{2}, y^{2}, x^{3}$, etc. in the set that contains $t_{1},..,t_{n}$?

Comment: We don't need to mention them. An element in $\langle S\rangle$ (where $S$ is a subset of $G$) is by definition a finite product of elements from $S$ and their inverses. So powers of $x$ and $y$ are elements in $\langle x,y\rangle$ anyway, because for example you can write $x^2=xx$. (so powers are indeed products of elements from $\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\})$.

Comment: So let's say $t_{i}$ is in somewhere in that list between $t_{1},...,t_{n} $ such that $t_{i}=xy$. Then isn't it wrong to use the $\in$ symbol?

Comment: I understand that you can express elements as a finite product of the following $x, y, x^{-1},y^{-1}$ but it's the notation you used i can't wrap my head around. You said $t_1,...,t_n\in\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\}$ when you simply mean that the former list elements are just finite products of the latter list elements, right sir?

Comment: No, $t_1,...,t_n$ are exactly elements in $\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\}$, not products of them. But then their product $t_1t_2...t_n$ is a finite product of elements from $\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\}$, which means $t_1t_2...t_n$ is an element in $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: What I did is the following: since $g\in\langle x,y\rangle$ we know $g$ is a finite product of elements from $\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\}$. So I just called the elements from this product $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$. That's it.

Comment: Crystal clear now. Thank you!